# Cors not blocking origins - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cors, rack-cors

I have on my cors.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'localhost:4000' # later change to the domain of the frontend app
    resource '*',
    headers: :any,
    methods: %i[get post put   patch delete options head],
    expose: [:Authorization]
  end
end
```

But when I am trying to make some API request with localhost:3000, it works when cors should be blocking it.

I am currently checking only in development.

I even tried to put a fake URL origin (other than localhost) but still `localhost:3000` can make API request

Comment: What port is the API running on?

Comment: You write: _it works when cors should be blocking it._ No, CORS doesn't block anything. Don't conflate the SOP and CORS, and don't think that CORS is a substitute for server-side authorisation.